# Sub-roles and role purchase

Tags: 7, users

I developed a site using Drupal 7 and the Ubercart module, where I sell user roles. I have sub-roles like the following.

- Producer

  - Co-producer
  - Ex-producer

How can I manage this? Is there any sub-role concept existing or manageable with category name in Ubercart?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like [Sub Users](https://drupal.org/project/subuser) module to set relation between two user types.

I also sell membership with help of Drupal Commerce in D7 & I have used same thing but some modified version of the module which you can find at my given link here --

https://drupal.org/node/2049703

I sell membership to have some access & sometimes I create a usertype who has got authority to create more sub user under him to have access allowed for that particular membership type.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create main role, just create sub roles as a main role. like your roles wil be co-producer and ex-producer.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal CORE has no concept of "sub-roles" - all roles are completely independent. So the relationship between them is just in your imagination unless you add additional function to Drupal core. One module that adds functionality similar to what you describe is https://www.drupal.org/project/role_inheritance

Regardless, I don't see how the question involves Ubercart. Ubercart grants access based on a role. The details of how that role is created or managed in core Drupal is of no concern to Ubercart.